# sun setting in the south

Tags: production-mistakes, san-andreas

In the last 5 minutes of San Andreas, there are at least 2 shots where the camera looks down the length of the Golden Gate Bridge (in San Francisco), and the sun is setting over the hills past it. The Bridge runs north-south, so the sun must be setting in the south. Was that a production gaffe, or was the implication that all of the San Francisco Peninsula had rotated 90 degrees so it now runs east-west?

Comment: Can you find video of this that we could look at?

Comment: Good suggestion, but the movie just came out last night so I couldn't find any pics of that. There are plenty of promotional stills of the destruction though!

Comment: Ah, I thought that might have been the one... I'm not a huge fan of disaster films, so I tend to ignore when they're released. :P

Answer (score 2):

I'd categorize this as a production gaffe. A [Google Image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=sunset%20golden%20gate%20bridge&espv=2&biw=1866&bih=889&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=WJloVf1txI_IBJPGgng&sqi=2&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&dpr=1) confirms that when you look directly into the sunset, the Golden Gate Bridge is in profile, since it runs north-south, as you said.

[image: Sunset behind the Golden Gate Bridge]

If the bridge is still standing, more than just the San Francisco peninsula would have to rotate 90 degrees. The landmass on the northern side of the bridge (Sausalito) would have to rotate with it.

If you zoom in on a [map of the San Andreas Fault](http://geology.com/san-andreas-fault/), you can see that it actually runs a few miles west of the bridge. So even if it did open up the way it did in the film, it shouldn't cause the whole region to the east to spin around 90 degrees. I think this is a well-spotted gaffe.

Comment: That movie was PACKED with gaffes.  But a whole lot of fun!!

Answer (score -4):

There are at least 13 OBVIOUS gaffes in this movie. As a San Franciscan I was embarrassed and annoyed. They filmed here so there are no excuses for these mistakes.
1. When they enter 555 California the view outside the window is the Bay Bridge. You can't see the Bay Bridge at this angle; the Bay Bridge is not a truss bridge; and none of the buildings in view are SF buildings.
2. There is a shot where people are walking through downtown buildings toward the Golden Gate bridge. Downtown and the GGB are on opposite sides of the city as opposed to popular belief.
3. If you're driving north from Bakersfield you're taking the 5. The San Andreas fault is shown spanning east to west across the 5. It doesn't. And Bakersfield is not an 1.5 hour from SF.
4. Lombard STREET, not Avenue.
5. Nob Hill is not the highest point in the city. Mount Davidson is.
6. Lombard is only a 15 minute walk from Nob Hill and you would not walk through Chinatown to get there.
7. Probably most disrespectful, the tallest building under construction in this movie was NOT EVEN A SAN FRANCISCO BUILDING. It is the under construction Wilshire Grand of Los Angeles. Our tallest building under construction is the Transbay Salesforce Tower. Hollywood dissed SF.
8. AT&T Park is on King St. Not the Embarcadero.
9. The San Andreas Fault is inland and could never trigger a tsunami in the direction of the Bay.
10. Bryant St is not located in the Financial District.
11. Not to do with SF but for as long as that girl was under water and without oxygen to her brain she would be brain dead, at best. She didn't breathe for about 4 minutes. You're dead after 2.
12. The Marin Headlands are incredibly windy, up to 60mph. You could never set up tents there.
13. And lastly, someone attached a flag on the defunct bridge. Ain't nobody shimming up those cables to hang no flags during an earthquake. Not accessible how it was portrayed.

Comment: and how does it answer the question?

Comment: It would have been best if you stayed to question asked.